# Как адаптировать кнопки?

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка

Все 6 кнопок "график" съезжают постоянно куда-то как только я меняю размер экрана, все остальное в флекс-боксе нормально остается. Что не так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
    .main-flex-container {
      display: flex;
      margin-top: 30px;
    }

    .flex-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }

    .column-reverse {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }


    /* отображение блоков ровномерно
        -------------------- */

    html {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: helvetica;
    background: rgba(250, 200, 160, 120);
}

header {
    text-align: center;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 20px;
}

body {
    padding: 10px;
}
/*-----------MENU-------------*/
.macmenu {
    height: 60px;
    margin-left: 230px
    /*высота общего блока*/
}

.button {
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    /*выравнивание блока по центру*/
    width: 400px;
    /*ширина всего блока с меню*/
}

.button a img,
.button a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    height:60px;
    width: 70px;

}

.button a {
    margin: 5px 5px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000000;
    font: normal normal 10px Verdana;
    text-decoration: none;
    word-wrap: normal;  /*запрещает автоматически разрывать слова на перенос*/
}

.macmenu a:hover img {
    height: 70px;
    width: 80px;
}

.button a:hover {
    font: normal bold 12px Verdana;
}


.colr {
    color: #2f2d2d;
    font-size: 100%;
    /* Размер шрифта */
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
    /* Параметры линии под текстом */
    font-weight: normal;
    /* Убираем жирное начертание */
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    /* Расстояние от текста до линии */
}

.col2 {
    display: block;
    width: 600px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #2f2d2d;
    font-size: 80%;
    /* Размер шрифта */

}
.main-flex-container {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 30px;
    
}

.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    
}

.column-reverse {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    
}

/* отображение блоков ровномерно
-------------------- */

.flex-container {
    margin: auto;
    width: 45%;
    padding: 2px;
    background: rgba(196, 196, 196, 0);
    border-radius: 10px;
    justify-content: center;

}

.column-reverse {
    margin: auto;
    float: right;
    width: 45%;
    padding: 2px;
    background: rgba(196, 196, 196, 0);
    border-radius: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
}

.flex-item {
    margin: 5px;
    height: 220px;
    padding: 13px;
    background: rgba(175, 175, 175, 0);
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.but1{
width: 95px;
height: 12px;    
margin-left: -180px;
margin-top: 540px;    
text-decoration:none; text-align:center; 
 padding:12px 18px; 
 border:solid 1px #004F72; 
 -webkit-border-radius:4px;
 -moz-border-radius:4px; 
 border-radius: 4px; 
 font:12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
 font-weight:bold; 
 color:#fcfcfc; 
 background-color:#3636e8; 
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3636e8 0%, #2c02d4 100%); 
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3636e8 0%, #2c02d4 100%); 
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3636e8 0%, #2c02d4 100%); 
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3636e8 0% ,#2c02d4 100%); 
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2c02d4', endColorstr='#2c02d4',GradientType=0 ); 
 background-image: linear-gradient(top, #3636e8 0% ,#2c02d4 100%);   
 -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff; 
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa,  inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;  
 box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;  
z-index: 999;    
  
  }.but1:hover{
 padding:11px 18px; 
 border:solid 1px #004F72; 
 -webkit-border-radius:4px;
 -moz-border-radius:4px; 
 border-radius: 4px; 
 font:12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
 font-weight:bold;    
 color:#ffffff; 
 background-color:#3ba4c7; 
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3ba4c7 0%, #1982a5 100%); 
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3ba4c7 0%, #1982a5 100%); 
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3ba4c7 0%, #1982a5 100%); 
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3ba4c7 0% ,#1982a5 100%); 
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1982a5', endColorstr='#1982a5',GradientType=0 ); 
 background-image: linear-gradient(top, #3ba4c7 0% ,#1982a5 100%);   
 -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff; 
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa,  inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;  
 box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;  
  
 }.but1:active{
 padding:11px 18px; 
 border:solid 1px #004F72; 
 -webkit-border-radius:4px;
 -moz-border-radius:4px; 
 border-radius: 4px; 
 font:12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
 font-weight:bold; 
 color:#fcfcfc; 
 background-color:#3636e8; 
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3636e8 0%, #2c02d4 100%); 
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3636e8 0%, #2c02d4 100%); 
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3636e8 0%, #2c02d4 100%); 
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3636e8 0% ,#2c02d4 100%); 
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2c02d4', endColorstr='#2c02d4',GradientType=0 ); 
 background-image: linear-gradient(top, #3636e8 0% ,#2c02d4 100%);   
 -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff; 
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa,  inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;  
 box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;  
  
 }
.hbut1{
position:fixed;     
width: 95px;
height: 12px;    
margin-left: 50em;
margin-top: -1.5em;   
display: inline-block;
outline: none;
cursor: pointer;
vertical-align: middle;    
text-decoration:none; text-align:center; 
 padding:12px 18px; 
 border:solid 1px #004F72; 
 -webkit-border-radius:4px;
 -moz-border-radius:4px; 
 border-radius: 4px; 
 font:12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
 font-weight:bold; 
 color:#fcfcfc; 
 background-color:#3636e8; 
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3636e8 0%, #2c02d4 100%); 
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3636e8 0%, #2c02d4 100%); 
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3636e8 0%, #2c02d4 100%); 
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3636e8 0% ,#2c02d4 100%); 
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2c02d4', endColorstr='#2c02d4',GradientType=0 ); 
 background-image: linear-gradient(top, #3636e8 0% ,#2c02d4 100%);   
 -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff; 
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa,  inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;  
 box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;  
z-index: 99999;    
  
  }.hbut1:hover{
 padding:11px 18px; 
 border:solid 1px #004F72; 
 -webkit-border-radius:4px;
 -moz-border-radius:4px; 
 border-radius: 4px; 
 font:12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
 font-weight:bold;    
 color:#ffffff; 
 background-color:#3ba4c7; 
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3ba4c7 0%, #1982a5 100%); 
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3ba4c7 0%, #1982a5 100%); 
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3ba4c7 0%, #1982a5 100%); 
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3ba4c7 0% ,#1982a5 100%); 
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1982a5', endColorstr='#1982a5',GradientType=0 ); 
 background-image: linear-gradient(top, #3ba4c7 0% ,#1982a5 100%);   
 -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff; 
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa,  inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;  
 box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;  
 z-index: 99999;       
  
 }.hbut1:active{
 padding:11px 18px; 
 border:solid 1px #004F72; 
 -webkit-border-radius:4px;
 -moz-border-radius:4px; 
 border-radius: 4px; 
 font:12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
 font-weight:bold; 
 color:#fcfcfc; 
 background-color:#3636e8; 
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3636e8 0%, #2c02d4 100%); 
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3636e8 0%, #2c02d4 100%); 
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3636e8 0%, #2c02d4 100%); 
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3636e8 0% ,#2c02d4 100%); 
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2c02d4', endColorstr='#2c02d4',GradientType=0 ); 
 background-image: linear-gradient(top, #3636e8 0% ,#2c02d4 100%);   
 -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff; 
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa,  inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;  
 box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;  
  z-index: 99999; 
 }
```

```html
<div class="main-flex-container">

  <!--ГИСТОГРАММ 1-->
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">
      <a href="chart1.html" class="hbut1">ГРАФИК</a>

      <!--ВЕРТИКАЛЬНАЯ ГИСТОГРАММ 1-->
      <div id="gistorgam1" style="min-width: 310px; height: 200px; margin-top:-20px;text-align:center;"></div>

      <!--ГОРИЗОНТАЛЬНЫЙ ГИСТОГРАММ 1-->
      <div id="horizontal1" style="min-width: 310px; height: 80px; margin-top:-15px;"></div>

    </div>
    <!--END-->

    <div class="flex-item">
      <a href="chart2.html" class="hbut1">ГРАФИК</a>
      <!--ВЕРТИКАЛЬНАЯ ГИСТОГРАММ 2-->
      <div id="gistorgam2" style="min-width: 310px; height: 200px; margin-top:-20px;text-align:center;"></div>

      <!--ГОРИЗОНТАЛЬНЫЙ ГИСТОГРАММ 2-->
      <div id="horizontal2" style="min-width: 310px; height: 80px; margin-top:-15px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <a href="chart3.html" class="hbut1">ГРАФИК</a>

      <!--ВЕРТИКАЛЬНАЯ ГИСТОГРАММ 3-->
      <div id="gistorgam3" style="min-width: 310px; height: 200px; margin-top:-20px;text-align:center;"></div>

      <!--ГОРИЗОНТАЛЬНЫЙ ГИСТОГРАММ 3-->
      <div id="horizontal3" style="min-width: 310px; height: 80px; margin-top:-15px;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column-reverse">
    <div class="flex-item">
      <a href="chart4.html" class="hbut1">ГРАФИК</a>

      <!--ВЕРТИКАЛЬНАЯ ГИСТОГРАММ 4-->
      <div id="gistorgam4" style="min-width: 310px; height: 200px; margin-top:-20px;text-align:center;"></div>

      <!--ГОРИЗОНТАЛЬНЫЙ ГИСТОГРАММ 4-->
      <div id="horizontal4" style="min-width: 310px; height: 80px; margin-top:-15px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <a href="chart5.html" class="hbut1">ГРАФИК</a>

      <!--ВЕРТИКАЛЬНАЯ ГИСТОГРАММ 5-->
      <div id="gistorgam5" style="min-width: 310px; height: 200px; margin-top:-20px;text-align:center;"></div>

      <!--ГОРИЗОНТАЛЬНЫЙ ГИСТОГРАММ 5-->
      <div id="horizontal5" style="min-width: 310px; height: 80px; margin-top:-15px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <a href="chart6.html" class="hbut1">ГРАФИК</a>

      <!--ВЕРТИКАЛЬНАЯ ГИСТОГРАММ 6-->
      <div id="gistorgam6" style="min-width: 310px; height: 200px; margin-top:-20px;text-align:center;"></div>

      <!--ГОРИЗОНТАЛЬНЫЙ ГИСТОГРАММ 4-->
      <div id="horizontal6" style="min-width: 310px; height: 80px; margin-top:-15px;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Попытался просмотреть что съезжает, так у меня все кнопки на своих местах, можно получить изображение вашей проблемы?

Comment: Да,сейчас скину

Comment: В таком виде оно и сьезжает

Comment: Добавьте пример с графиками

Comment: добавил все уже

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.main-flex-container {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.column-reverse {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}


/* отображение блоков ровномерно
        -------------------- */

html {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: helvetica;
  background: rgba(250, 200, 160, 120);
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 20px;
}

body {
  padding: 10px;
}


/*-----------MENU-------------*/

.macmenu {
  height: 60px;
  margin-left: 230px
  /*высота общего блока*/
}

.button {
  margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
  /*выравнивание блока по центру*/
  width: 400px;
  /*ширина всего блока с меню*/
}

.button a img,
.button a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  height: 60px;
  width: 70px;
}

.button a {
  margin: 5px 5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
  font: normal normal 10px Verdana;
  text-decoration: none;
  word-wrap: normal;
  /*запрещает автоматически разрывать слова на перенос*/
}

.macmenu a:hover img {
  height: 70px;
  width: 80px;
}

.button a:hover {
  font: normal bold 12px Verdana;
}

.colr {
  color: #2f2d2d;
  font-size: 100%;
  /* Размер шрифта */
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
  /* Параметры линии под текстом */
  font-weight: normal;
  /* Убираем жирное начертание */
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  /* Расстояние от текста до линии */
}

.col2 {
  display: block;
  width: 600px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2f2d2d;
  font-size: 80%;
  /* Размер шрифта */
}

.main-flex-container {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.column-reverse {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}


/* отображение блоков ровномерно
-------------------- */

.flex-container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 45%;
  padding: 2px;
  background: rgba(196, 196, 196, 0);
  border-radius: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.column-reverse {
  margin: auto;
  float: right;
  width: 45%;
  padding: 2px;
  background: rgba(196, 196, 196, 0);
  border-radius: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-item {
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 220px;
  padding: 13px;
  background: rgba(175, 175, 175, 0);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.but1 {
  width: 95px;
  height: 12px;
  margin-left: -180px;
  margin-top: 540px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px 18px;
  border: solid 1px #004F72;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fcfcfc;
  background-color: #3636e8;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3636e8 0%, #2c02d4 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3636e8 0%, #2c02d4 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3636e8 0%, #2c02d4 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3636e8 0%, #2c02d4 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2c02d4', endColorstr='#2c02d4', GradientType=0);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #3636e8 0%, #2c02d4 100%);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
  z-index: 999;
}

.but1:hover {
  padding: 11px 18px;
  border: solid 1px #004F72;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #3ba4c7;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3ba4c7 0%, #1982a5 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3ba4c7 0%, #1982a5 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3ba4c7 0%, #1982a5 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3ba4c7 0%, #1982a5 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1982a5', endColorstr='#1982a5', GradientType=0);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #3ba4c7 0%, #1982a5 100%);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
}

.but1:active {
  padding: 11px 18px;
  border: solid 1px #004F72;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fcfcfc;
  background-color: #3636e8;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3636e8 0%, #2c02d4 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3636e8 0%, #2c02d4 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3636e8 0%, #2c02d4 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3636e8 0%, #2c02d4 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2c02d4', endColorstr='#2c02d4', GradientType=0);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #3636e8 0%, #2c02d4 100%);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
}

.hbut1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 95px;
  height: 12px;
  right: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px 18px;
  border: solid 1px #004F72;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fcfcfc;
  background-color: #3636e8;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3636e8 0%, #2c02d4 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3636e8 0%, #2c02d4 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3636e8 0%, #2c02d4 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3636e8 0%, #2c02d4 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2c02d4', endColorstr='#2c02d4', GradientType=0);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #3636e8 0%, #2c02d4 100%);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
  z-index: 99999;
}

.hbut1:hover {
  padding: 11px 18px;
  border: solid 1px #004F72;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #3ba4c7;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3ba4c7 0%, #1982a5 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3ba4c7 0%, #1982a5 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3ba4c7 0%, #1982a5 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3ba4c7 0%, #1982a5 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1982a5', endColorstr='#1982a5', GradientType=0);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #3ba4c7 0%, #1982a5 100%);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
  z-index: 99999;
}

.hbut1:active {
  padding: 11px 18px;
  border: solid 1px #004F72;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fcfcfc;
  background-color: #3636e8;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3636e8 0%, #2c02d4 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3636e8 0%, #2c02d4 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3636e8 0%, #2c02d4 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3636e8 0%, #2c02d4 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2c02d4', endColorstr='#2c02d4', GradientType=0);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #3636e8 0%, #2c02d4 100%);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-flex-container">

  <!--ГИСТОГРАММ 1-->
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">
      <a href="chart1.html" class="hbut1">ГРАФИК</a>

      <!--ВЕРТИКАЛЬНАЯ ГИСТОГРАММ 1-->
      <div id="gistorgam1" style="min-width: 310px; height: 200px; margin-top:-20px;text-align:center;"></div>

      <!--ГОРИЗОНТАЛЬНЫЙ ГИСТОГРАММ 1-->
      <div id="horizontal1" style="min-width: 310px; height: 80px; margin-top:-15px;"></div>

    </div>
    <!--END-->

    <div class="flex-item">
      <a href="chart2.html" class="hbut1">ГРАФИК</a>
      <!--ВЕРТИКАЛЬНАЯ ГИСТОГРАММ 2-->
      <div id="gistorgam2" style="min-width: 310px; height: 200px; margin-top:-20px;text-align:center;"></div>

      <!--ГОРИЗОНТАЛЬНЫЙ ГИСТОГРАММ 2-->
      <div id="horizontal2" style="min-width: 310px; height: 80px; margin-top:-15px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <a href="chart3.html" class="hbut1">ГРАФИК</a>

      <!--ВЕРТИКАЛЬНАЯ ГИСТОГРАММ 3-->
      <div id="gistorgam3" style="min-width: 310px; height: 200px; margin-top:-20px;text-align:center;"></div>

      <!--ГОРИЗОНТАЛЬНЫЙ ГИСТОГРАММ 3-->
      <div id="horizontal3" style="min-width: 310px; height: 80px; margin-top:-15px;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column-reverse">
    <div class="flex-item">
      <a href="chart4.html" class="hbut1">ГРАФИК</a>

      <!--ВЕРТИКАЛЬНАЯ ГИСТОГРАММ 4-->
      <div id="gistorgam4" style="min-width: 310px; height: 200px; margin-top:-20px;text-align:center;"></div>

      <!--ГОРИЗОНТАЛЬНЫЙ ГИСТОГРАММ 4-->
      <div id="horizontal4" style="min-width: 310px; height: 80px; margin-top:-15px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <a href="chart5.html" class="hbut1">ГРАФИК</a>

      <!--ВЕРТИКАЛЬНАЯ ГИСТОГРАММ 5-->
      <div id="gistorgam5" style="min-width: 310px; height: 200px; margin-top:-20px;text-align:center;"></div>

      <!--ГОРИЗОНТАЛЬНЫЙ ГИСТОГРАММ 5-->
      <div id="horizontal5" style="min-width: 310px; height: 80px; margin-top:-15px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <a href="chart6.html" class="hbut1">ГРАФИК</a>

      <!--ВЕРТИКАЛЬНАЯ ГИСТОГРАММ 6-->
      <div id="gistorgam6" style="min-width: 310px; height: 200px; margin-top:-20px;text-align:center;"></div>

      <!--ГОРИЗОНТАЛЬНЫЙ ГИСТОГРАММ 4-->
      <div id="horizontal6" style="min-width: 310px; height: 80px; margin-top:-15px;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Как пример, на кнопке поменять fixed на absolute и дать отступ справа

Comment: Спасибо большое )